# Uncaught exception in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog 
I got this coding from a online video

```
what_age(Other) :-
    Grade is Other -5,
    format('~w Go to the college',[Grade]).
```

But When I changed the code as below

```
what_age(Other) :- 
    Other -5,
    format('~w ~s Go to the college',[Other]).
```

I get the error

```
- what_age(30).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(-)/2),what_age/1)
```

Comment: `Grade is Other-5` makes sense (assign the result of a subtraction to `Grade`), but what is `Other -5` alone supposed to do? Besides, your format string has two placeholders, but the argument list has only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Prolog interpreter expresses the error in the Prolog language itself, which makes the message a bit cryptic.

```
error(existence_error(procedure,(-)/2),what_age/1)
```

This basically says: in your definition of the predicate `what_age` (of arity 1), you are referring to a non-existent procedure named `(-)` of arity 2.

The error occurs in this part of your rule:

```
Other - 5
```

Your program does not define any rules for the minus operator; hence the error.

If you were expecting a calculation to take place here, think again. Unlike most other programming languages, arithmetic expressions are left unevaluated in Prolog. `1+2` is not 3. `1+2` is just that; an operator with two arguments. To force evaluation, you need the 'is' operator. Which is exactly what was done in the original code:

```
Grade is Other - 5
```

No error here, simply because operator `(is)/2` *does* have a (built-in) rule defined. This rule will do an arithmetic evaluation of whatever term is on the right-hand side (here: `Other - 5`), and unify the result of that calculation with the term on the left-hand side (`Grade`). For example, if `Other` is 8, then `Grade` must become 3 for the rule to succeed.